# PowerShell list installed third party application update

Tags: powershell, updates, desktop-application

Is there a powershell command to return a list of installed non-microsoft application updates?
**Example**: after installing softwareA and installing update to softwareA -> one can see the installed update in the Control Panel - View Installed Updates section
Is there a PowerShell command or simple script to return true if update is installed or false if update is not installed?

Comment: You can get the installed version of a software with powershell. You can comapre the installed version with the version number of the update

Comment: In my case applied update doesn't change version, need to extract its name in some way.

Comment: Only possibility I see is to look at the installed date of the application or something that changed in the source files of the application. Maybe someone else has an idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this and replace the program name string with your program. Use wildcards to help narrow down the program name. An expected output will be the uninstall string last write time. Making the assumption that the last write time of the files are changing when there's a patch.

```
$programname = "Notepad++*"
$32bit = Get-ItemProperty 
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
$64bit = Get-ItemProperty 
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
$programs = $32bit + $64bit
foreach ($program in $programs){
$program = Write-Output $program | where Displayname -like $programname
if ($program.DisplayName -ne $null) {
$LastModified = (Get-Item $program.uninstallstring).lastwritetime

                 $properties = @{
                                 ProgramName = $program.DisplayName
                                 Publisher = $program.Publisher
                                 Version = $program.DisplayVersion
                                 UninstallString = $program.UninstallString
                                 LastModified = $LastModified
 }
                 $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
                 Write-Output $obj
                 }
 }
```

Comment: this script results in following output: cmdlet Get-ItemProperty at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:

Comment: @misha - Make sure you are passing `$32bit = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*` and `$64bit = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*` as a single line cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.ParentDisplayName -like "*foo*" }
```

This returns an object where `ParentDisplayName` is your program and `DisplayVersion` is the update version.